# XPath Expression to select specific node and it's attributes having specified multiple attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a configuration file with multiple transaction plugins configured inside. Below is a sample of a transaction plugin. The structure of the transaction plugin is the same for all that may exist in the config file. How can I be able to query the source named "mmc" and get all it's steps. The "mmc" source could also exist in another different transaction configuration ?

I wrote

```
String expression = "/plugins/transaction[@code=501110]/source[@name=mmc]/step/@*";
```

but it did not give me any results

```
<transaction code="501110" name="A transaction" plugin="com.Transaction.ATransaction">
    <source name="mmc">
        <step id="0">
            <result code="*">
                <destination>mms</destination>
            </result>
        </step>
        <step id="1">
            <result code="0000">
                <destination>brmc</destination>
            </result>
            <result code="0012">
                <destination>cre</destination>
            </result>
            <result code="default">
                <destination>nc</destination>
            </result>
        </step>
    </source>
    <source name="mms">
        <step id="1">
            <result code="0000">
                <destination>bnk</destination>
            </result>
            <result code="default">
                <destination>nc</destination>
            </result>
        </step>
    </source>
    <source name="bnk">
        <step id="1">
            <result code="0000">
                <destination>nc</destination>
            </result>
            <result code="default">
                <destination>nc</destination>
            </result>
        </step>
    </source>
</transaction>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a `plugins` element in your sample input, but assuming that it's there and you just didn't show it, an XPath along these lines should do it:

```
/plugins/transaction[@code = '501110']/source[@name = 'mmc']/step
```

This will select all of the `step` elements beneath the specified path.

The quotes around `501110` aren't strictly  necessary in this particular case, because `code` is a number, but on the off chance that it could contain a non-number character, it makes sense to treat it as a string value here.

Comment: Thank you sir, the quotes were the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
/plugins/transaction[@code="501110"]/source[@name="mmc"]/step
```

if you want all `destination` elements :

```
/plugins/transaction[@code="501110"]/source[@name="mmc"]/step/*[@name=contains(., "result code")]/destination/text()
```

if you want all `result code` :

```
/plugins/transaction[@code="501110"]/source[@name="mmc"]/step/*[@name=contains(., "result code")]/@code
```